# Password containing semicolon in an Azure Release variable

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, connection-string

I have a web application that accesses an SQL Server database. The connection string is stored in an Azure Devops Release pipeline variable. As the password contains a semicolon, I get an error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification..." I know that the problem should be resolved by using single quotation marks around the password, and this would work if e.g. I had the connection string in a config file. But as it is in the variable, the login just fails, as the quotation marks are probably seen as parts of the password.

The connection string has the following format:

```
Data Source=23.123.34.121;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;UID=Username;Password=Pass;word;Connect Timeout=15;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: I used double quotes like this: Data Source=23.123.34.121;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;UID=Username;Password="Pass;word";Connect Timeout=15;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;   but the login still fails. Or maybe you meant two single-quotes on each side?

Comment: @ThomA And I forgot to thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Microsoft talks about escaping in [ADO.NET connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/connection-strings#connection-string-syntax) with `"` and `'` characters (even including an example with `;` characters), and in [JDBC connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url#escaping-values-in-the-connection-url) with `{` and `}` characters. I suspect your problem here, though, is actually DevOps itself.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I agree, but there must be some way around it...

Comment: Is this in a YAML pipeline definition? Have you tried YAML string escapes, i.e.: `'this is a string.'` versus `'It''s OK if they''re using contractions.'`, so overall you'd have something like `connectionString: '...;Password=''Pass;word'';...'`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No, it is not a YAML definition. Just classic. I did try two single quotes, but got "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 67"